# A CLT approximation question where $n$ is unknown.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I’m a little stumped by this question:

> A fair coin is flipped repeatedly until we get “H” exactly 120 times. We’ll mark with $X$ the number of flips in which we got the result “T”.  approximate with CLT $P(X \geq 137)$

my progress so far:

had I known the total number of coin flips I would’ve been able to answer the question with relative ease. I’ve started as I usually do by defining $X_i$.
$$X_i = \begin{cases}1 & \text{The ith flip landed on “T”} \\ 0 & \text{Otherwise}
 \end{cases} $$
I know $$X = \sum_{i=1}^{n=X+120} X_i$$ and finding $\mu$ and $\textsf{Var}(X_i)$ is doable as well: $E(X_i) = P(X_i=1) = 0.5$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{p \cdot q} = \sqrt{0.5^2} = \frac12$. 
I’m starting to experience problems trying to get to the form of CLT - I can’t rid the right expression of X.
$$P\left(\frac{X - \mu n}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} \geq \frac{137 -\frac12(X+120)}{\frac12 \sqrt{X+120}}\right)$$
I don’t know how to continue from here.

Comment: the answer is 0.16

Comment: I would find the expected number of flips to get one Head and the variance (it is rather more than your calculation), then add $120$ independent copies of this to find the mean and variance of the sum.  Using a Normal approximation, I might also have a continuity correction.

Comment: If i understand you correctly: the expected number of flips to get one head is 2 (geom(0.5)). So n = H_1+H_2+…+H_120 where they’re all independent geometric variables. So you’d do basically $P(n-120 \geq 137) = P(n \geq 257)$ and for our CLT the number at the top of the sum would be 120?

Comment: That kind of thing.   I get about $0.1440$ with a negative binomial distribution and $0.1434$ with a continuity-corrected Normal approximation

Comment: I tried doing as you’ve suggested but this question is taken from a test without calculator and I’ve reached an impasse. https://imgur.com/a/WOGnLqV

Comment: we are given select values of the canonized normal’s CDF.

Comment: also minor error - the root n should’ve been a root j